# Non-English special folder names in Vista/Win7

Tags: windows-7, localization, windows-vista, special-folders

In non-english versions Windows Vista and Windows 7 the usual special folders (such as the "My documents" folder) have dual naming: For instance "My documents" can be accessed (in german systems) via

```
C:\Users\Username\Documents
```

But is displayed (in explorer and file choosing dialogs) as

```
C:\Benutzer\Username\Eigene Dokumente
```

In my (C#) application, I would like to display the second form but need to use the first one internally. So I'm looking for some function to convert e.g. the result of `Environment.GetFolderPath()` (which is always the english name) to the localized form.

Since I do not know, how this feature is called (and my english is somehow limited), I don't even know how to google it.

Any hints are very appreciated!

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some more research, I found out myself: The concepts I was looking for were

- [Junction points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Desktop.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144102%28VS.85%29.aspx) using the (undocumented) `LocalizedResourceName` entry (only documented for Windows CE)

I will open up a separate question about a function for getting this "LocalizedResourceName" automatically (I do not want to look it up manually for each directory in my path...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`. It should return the localized path.

Reference: [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)